# Please refer a GUI Modelling tools for a .Net object database?

Tags: user-interface, data-modeling, object-oriented-database

I am planning to use an object database, say eloquera (http://eloquera.com/page/home.aspx).

If I use RDBMS as storage, there are a lot of GUI modelling tools.

But I cannot find one for object database. In other words, a GUI modelling tools to generate .Net (C#) code.

If you know one, please tell me.

Thanks,

Ying

---

Actually I have had a look at a few UML tools. They lack some features I need.

I rearranged my idea and create a new question here, A component/tools of knowledge based modeling for .Net (
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227543/a-component-tools-of-knowledge-based-modeling-for-net ).

Sorry, this question is closed.

Thank you,

Ying

Comment: Use the built-in class diagrams in Visual Studio?? After all, you're only ever going to be building and using C# classes, right?

Comment: Yes, only C# classes. But I need more modelling specified features. I just updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking for an IDE(GUI) that develops C# Code?  Web Expression (FREE) / Visual Studio / Expression Designer / Altova (various).

Not sure what exactly you are looking for as GUI Modeling is to general a term to really identify what you are looking for.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools

Comment: Thank you. I checked the tools in your mentioned list and updated my question.